# problem with establishing connection with Container website with TDS

Tags: docker, tds, container

facing issue with  establishing TDS connection with container website.
i already setup local instance using https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/tree/develop/custom-images its is working fine. I'm trying to connect with TDS with the created container cm websites, to check the tds sync & deploy functionality. I'm not sure whats the deploy folder to put ,i tried using
`..\..\docker\deploy`
. but its not working. can you please guide
[image]
[image]
[image]

Website is up and running and can able to login to sitecore as well

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like TDS is not able to read the URL so could you please make sure - 
 - Docker is up and running and you are able to browse and Sitecore login into your website with the above domain
 - try by specifying the port in your `Source Web Url`

Comment: Yes i can able to browse the website and Login to sitecore. everything works except TDS

Comment: Do you have to install a connector within the running sitecore instance? If that is the case, then you may need to build your image to have the connector there by default since you can't reliably install packages in a container.

Comment: https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples/tree/develop/custom-images doesn't come with TDS connector installation by default right. Any idea on how to build the image with connector by default ?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue.

Initially i ran init.ps1 and then did some corrections in **.env** file to the domain. like **cmm**.dockerexamples.localhost instead of **cm**.dockerexamples.localhost

- Removed existing container by running  `docker-compose down`
- edited **.env** to use domain to use old **cm**.dockerexamples.localhost
- Ran this command `docker-compose up -d`

After this i can able to establish a connection with TDS
[image]

i can able to communicate with TDS and again

Sitecore Deploy folder used **"....\docker\deploy\website"**

[image]

***Lesson Learned : Dont modify .env directly because its a auto generated file. We can modify only docker compose file.***

Comment: It should actually be the opposite - you should only update the `.env` file as those contain your instance specific variables. Your `docker-compose.yml` file should stay untouched.

Comment: All modifications on the images parameterized via .ENV file.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeChang , .env file values will be autogenerated after running .\init.ps1 -LicenseXmlPath.

Comment: @BalajiBalasubramanian You shouldn't need to run `init.ps1` after the initial project initialization.